# Python pyinstaller - Error AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I finished my personal project in Python and i'm trying to create an .EXE, *everything is working perfectly inside Visual Studio*, but when I try to run the .exe inside the folder "dist" i get the following messagebox warning

```
Unhandled exception in script

Failed to execute script 'sistema' due to unhandled exception: 'App' object has no attribute 'Cursor'
```

How to solve this? What causes it?

Below is my code to connect db:

```
def connect(self):
        os.chdir("C:")
        os.chdir("C:\\instantclient_21_3")
        try: 
            self.conexao = cx_Oracle.connect("~~ my string connection~~")
            self.cursor = self.conexao.cursor()
            
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: 
            pass
```

note: everything is working perfectly when I run through VS Code

note2: i used the command pyinstaller --onefile --w sistema.py

Comment: first you could print errors which you get in except - maybe you got problem in VSCode but you didn't see because you used `pass` in except. Next you may add `print()` to see what you have in variables and which lines are executed - to see which line makes problem and if some variable doesn't have wrong value. And run .exe in console to see if it display some error message. maybe it needs some module or C/C++ libraries and you have to add it manually to special config file `.spec`

Comment: read also documentation - especially [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) and [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html)